# how to change the page redirect in dnn using database

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to update the dnn's default page redirect to one of the custom page, using database, because on the admin tab when I try to click on site setting and after changing the default homepage setting and click on update, I gets an object reference error, I don't have much time to resolve this error, so tried to change the setting using database, but could not found from which table I can change this default homepage settings...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your idea properly, you can modify the HomeTabId field in the PortalLocalization table. Put the ID of the new home page into this field. You should also know your portal ID if you have a few portals stored in the same DB.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add my experience.

I was fooling (very correct term) around with redirects and admin modules, then logged out and could not get back in. Typing "/Login.aspx" had me redirected to Home.aspx and somehow that went into this infinite loop.

So I edited the dbo.PortalLocalization.
The value for the "HomeTabId" and the "LoginTabId" was the same. 
Luckily I´d´added a splash page which I could reach outside login. 
So I changed the "LoginTabId" value to that of the "SplashTabId", then cleared the browser cache.

The login-module appeared on my splash page and I could log in again. :D

Thanx for that advice! Just brilliant.